# Window Function to increment over column on logical criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I am looking for a way to add a user agnostic "session" column based on the following criteria.

1) each user defines his own session

2) a time lapse of +10 minutes starts a new session for a given user.

Thus for the input:

```
| user_id | datetime_col     |
------------------------------
|1        |  01/01/2020 13:00|
|1        |  01/01/2020 13:01|
|1        |  01/01/2020 13:02|
|1        |  01/01/2020 13:20|
|1        |  01/01/2020 13:21|
|1        |  01/01/2020 13:22|
|1        |  01/01/2020 13:23|
|2        |  01/01/2020 13:00|
|2        |  01/01/2020 13:01|
|2        |  01/01/2020 13:02|
|2        |  01/01/2020 13:03|
|2        |  01/01/2020 13:04|
|3        |  01/01/2020 13:00|
|3        |  01/01/2020 13:01|
|3        |  01/01/2020 13:02|
|3        |  01/01/2020 13:03|
|3        |  01/01/2020 13:04|
```

I would want the following output:

```
| user_id | datetime_col     | seesion_id|
------------------------------------------
|1        |  01/01/2020 13:00|     0     |
|1        |  01/01/2020 13:01|     0     |
|1        |  01/01/2020 13:02|     0     |
|1        |  01/01/2020 13:20|     1     |
|1        |  01/01/2020 13:21|     1     |
|1        |  01/01/2020 13:22|     1     |
|1        |  01/01/2020 13:23|     1     |
|2        |  01/01/2020 13:00|     2     |
|2        |  01/01/2020 13:01|     2     |
|2        |  01/01/2020 13:02|     2     |
|2        |  01/01/2020 13:03|     2     |
|2        |  01/01/2020 13:04|     2     |
|3        |  01/01/2020 13:00|     3     |
|3        |  01/01/2020 13:01|     3     |
|3        |  01/01/2020 13:02|     3     |
|3        |  01/01/2020 13:03|     3     |
|3        |  01/01/2020 13:04|     3     |
```

Conceputally speaking I would want to calculate the time difference between each row for each user and then increment each time the user_id changes or when the time lag is greater than 10 minutes. I can do something like

```
SELECT *,
DATE_PART('minutes', datetime_col - LAG(datetime_col, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY datetime_col)) AS grp
FROM Table1
```

And get

```
| user_id | datetime_col     | grp       |
------------------------------------------
|1        |  01/01/2020 13:00|   (null)  |
|1        |  01/01/2020 13:01|     1     |
|1        |  01/01/2020 13:02|     1     |
|1        |  01/01/2020 13:20|    18     |
|1        |  01/01/2020 13:21|     1     |
|1        |  01/01/2020 13:22|     1     |
|1        |  01/01/2020 13:23|     1     |
|2        |  01/01/2020 13:00|   (null)  |
|2        |  01/01/2020 13:01|     1     |
|2        |  01/01/2020 13:02|     1     |
|2        |  01/01/2020 13:03|     1     |
|2        |  01/01/2020 13:04|     1     |
|3        |  01/01/2020 13:00|   (null)  |
|3        |  01/01/2020 13:01|     1     |
|3        |  01/01/2020 13:02|     1     |
|3        |  01/01/2020 13:03|     1     |
|3        |  01/01/2020 13:04|     1     |
```

But from here I'm stumped, how can I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate separate sessions for each user, by using `lag()` and a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) filter (where prev_dt < datetime_col - interval '10 minute') over (partition by user_id order by datetime_col) as session_id
from (select t.*,
             lag(datetime_col) over (partition by user_id order by datetime_col) as prev_dt
      from table1 t
     ) t;
```

The lag gets the previous date.  Then, only transitions more than 10 minutes apart are counted to get the `session_id`.

This makes the most sense to me.

But you seem to want to accumulate these by `USER_ID` first and then the date/time (by date/time overall makes more sense to me).  That seems weird, but you can use `dense_rank()`:

```
with s as (
      select t.*,
             count(*) filter (where prev_dt < datetime_col - interval '10 minute') over (partition by user_id order by datetime_col) as session_id
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(datetime_col) over (partition by user_id order by datetime_col) as prev_dt
            from table1 t
           ) t
     )
select s.*,
        dense_rank() over (order by user_id, session_id) - 1 as new_session_id
from  s
order by user_id, datetime_col;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=970fffa73f3ca239fade03bf42a0f273) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I like the first way first, only because its closer to what I was trying to do. The reason to accumulate by `user_id` first is that two users at operating at the same time define different sessions.  I honestly don't understand why this works.